# 'Length' issue with Google Analytics API Report Automation (magic)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, dashboard

I've been using this [Google Analytics API query tool](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/report-automation-magic) but now almost every time I try to "Get Data" for a Core Report or MCF report it tells me there is an issue with 'length'.  This is the message it portrays:

```
Error executing query1: Cannot read property "length" from undefined
```

Nothing should have changed in the script editor so I have no idea where this issue came from.  None of the metrics/dimensions/filters I use have the word 'length'.  I keep my max-results to each query under 100.

If you can help please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, fixed this issue.  Forgot to place a dimension for my data pull.  Woops